# Search multiple page website for HTML element of given class

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web-crawler

I was having some problems with a newly added jQueryUI dialog where the buttons were not being displayed correctly, and tracked it down to some CSS I had in one of my external style sheets.  Before just changing the CSS, I would like to confirm that some other page doesn't require it.

How can I find all elements in multiple pages which contain the element of a given class?

I expect that if the dialog only exists after the user performs some specific action, it will be very difficult to do, so it is okay to assume that upon page load, the dialog is created.

PHP and JavaScript solutions are both acceptable as well as a 3rd party webcrawler, etc.

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button {
  //bla bla bla
  color:#ffffff;
  //bla bla bla
}
```

EDIT.  One possible solution is to put the following on every page and then manually go to every page.  While I don't mind putting the JavaScript on every page, I would rather some solution which automates the crawling of all pages as there are quite a few.  Maybe some PHP crawling script and then use Ajax to send any pages which have the element to the server?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){
        if ( $( ".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button" ).length ) {
            console.log($( ".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button" ).length+' elements found on page.');
            $( ".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button" ).each(function( index ) {
                console.log( 'Element '+index+' found', this );
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you are unix I would suggest `grep` if Windows try a decent editor, they usually have a good find tool as part of them

Comment: Yeah, just download the source code and do a search and replace.

Comment: @Ciprian  The source code will not have the element as it only exists by being rendered by JavaScript.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Yes, I am using Unix.  How could `grep` be used as the raw HTML doesn't contain the element?

Comment: HHmmmmm you got me there

Comment: You might use a Chrome extension to check. I know there are many, but I can't name any one off the top of my head.

Comment: I would use wget or elinks with grep. Doesn't exactly content with the JQuery... Since each page has to be rendered, I would use FireBug. You can have it highlight text in it's console for easy ways to find it.